# How to add notifications count on list ember cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I want to add notification component like facebook notification count in my app.Challenge is that how i refresh notification as per changes added.But problem is that when page render first time,model data fetched.When we change some data of model and switch to other screen.Model didnt change...I have to refresh browser url.I want when browser URL changed refresh model each time.please help me out with feasible solution.

Comment: [`queryParams`](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/routing/query-params/) with `refreshModel` true is best fit for your use case

Comment: I did not get your solution please provide more detail...i hav done model  refresh on button but how do achieve when browser url change